# Integer.decode() in Spring application context

Tags: java, spring, properties, refactoring

How to pass an integer value from properties to application, if this value can be stored in octal / decimal / hexadecimal form?

properties example:

```
 app.size=0120
```

// should be 80 (dec).

spring context:

```
<bean id="resource">
    <property name="size">
        <bean class="java.lang.Integer" factory-method="decode">
            <constructor-arg name="nm">
                <bean class="java.lang.String">
                    <constructor-arg value="${app.size}"/>
                </bean>
            </constructor-arg>
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The above doesn't work:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error
>   creating bean with name 'resource' defined in ServletContext
>   resource [/WEB-INF/context.xml]:
>
> Cannot create inner bean 'java.lang.Integer#159c5db' of type [java.lang.Integer] while setting
>   bean property 'size';
>
> nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException:
>   Error creating bean with name 'java.lang.Integer#159c5db' defined in
>   ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/context.xml]:
>
> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through constructor argument with
>   index 0 of type [java.lang.String]: Ambiguous factory method argument
>   types - did you specify the correct bean references as factory method
>   arguments?

I know I can pass `size` as string, and then [`decode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#decode(java.lang.String)) it in java code. But it seems right to me to do this transformation in context. Is it possible?

---

The following works fine with decimal and hexadecimal numbers:

```
<bean id="resource">
    <property name="size" value="${app.size}" />
</bean>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to the [@Evgeniy Dorofeev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1831293/evgeniy-dorofeev)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16479622/1429387).

This worked:

```
<bean id="resource">
    <property name="size">
        <bean class="java.lang.Integer" factory-method="decode">
            <constructor-arg value="${app.size}" type="java.lang.String" />
        </bean>
    </property>
</bean>
```